# Does HttpsURLConnection.getInputStream() makes automatic retries?

Tags: java, timeout, httpsurlconnection

I am making a service request to a server using HttpsURLConnection like the code below :

```
URL url = new URL("service/url");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectionTimeout(300000);
connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
parse (connection.getInputStream());
```

Service sometimes may take longer time, so ideally I should expect a TimeOut Exception but instead the client is making a retry and sending the same request again. Is there a way to explicitly disable any kind of retries? And I am not even sure if the set timeout methods are making any difference.

I am using Java 1.6

UPDATE
I tried connect() and getResponseCode() instead of getInputStream() but same behaviour:

```
URL url = new URL("service/url");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectionTimeout(300000);
connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
connection.connect();
connection.getResponseCode();
```

even this is making 2 requests.

UPDATE
[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) fixed the issue. In HttpClient you can explicitly set retry to false

Comment: How did you infer it is retrying?

Comment: 2 exactly same requests are coming up in the server logs. And request is failing due to duplicate request.

Comment: Please use a tool like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to check if this is a client side issue.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling `openConnection()` and `connect()`, just call `openConnection()`.